# Force run MakeFile rule to run shell command

Tags: unix, makefile

I have the following rule in my make file which runs only a shell command

```
install:
    $(shell insmod kdisk.ko)
```

but when I do `> make install`, it always says that `make: 'install' is up to date.`

How can I force it to run the shell command?

Comment: As a side note to my answer, as it seems that you are new to **make** I would share the following opinion. The **GNU make** program has a *terrible* documentation – too long, few examples – and is quite hard to program, esp. as it has no predicate to tell if a target exists or not. I understand **GNU Make** is useful as a backend for **automake** or other  suimilar generators. If you want to write makefiles yourself, I would recommand to use **BSD Make**. See my [BSD Owl](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl) project and its documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to declare the target as

```
 .PHONY: install
install: kdisk.ko
    insmod kdisk.ko
```

This tells the **make** program that:

1. the `install` target requires `kdisk.ko` before it can be started
2. the `install` target is a *phony* target and will not try to produce a `install` file, just to do something useful.
3. the recipe bound to install is `insmod kdisk.ko`.

With your declaration, the command `insmod kdisk.ko` will be processed as **make** reads the file and its output will be used as a recipe for the `install` target. Quite not what you want.

Comment: Your `.PHONY` syntax looks backwards to me.  I've always seen it the other way around -- `.PHONY: install` not `install: .PHONY`.

Comment: The `.PHONY` also expresses that the target should be made even if there is actually already a new file whose name is `install`.

Comment: @triplee Thank you for the hint about `.PHONY` I used inadvertantly the **BSD Make** syntax! For the effect of `.PHONY` you mention, this a consequence of 2. that is worth to mention, thanks!